# SUMIF with filtered range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

This formula currently gets me the sum of all the **positive** values in column D which fall into `April 2019` (M column contains dates).

```
=SUMIFS(D18:D2834,M18:M2834,">="&DATE(2019,4,1),M18:M2834,"<"&DATE(2019,5,1),D18:D2834,">"&0)
```

I'm trying to change this formula to only sum the values in the D column which are **positive** **OR** where the value in the **C** column contains some text. I can write this condition as

```
"*some text*"
```

using wildcards, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into this formula.

```
Column C.       Column D        Column M



some text          200           03/08/2020
some more text     500           02/04/2019
bla bla            -100          01/01/2020
```

Comment: I may be able to help but it would help me if you could slim down your data and share an excel file or at least a picture of where everything is at so I can take a look visually (along with the formulas).

Comment: so there's only 3 columns here that are of concern - `Column C` contains text, `Column D` contains the numbers I want to sum, `Column M` contains dates

Comment: Yep that makes sense.  Looking at Fernando's answer that's a good route to go simply adding another sumifs statement and adding them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your explanation in the comments, I would do:

```
=SUMIFS(D18:D2834,M18:M2834,">="&DATE(2019,4,1),M18:M2834,"<"&DATE(2019,5,1)) - SUMIFS(D18:D2834,M18:M2834,">="&DATE(2019,4,1),M18:M2834,"<"&DATE(2019,5,1),D18:D2834,"<=0",C18:C2834,"<>*some text*")
```

1. Sum everything in April 2019
2. Then subtract the scenario that fits in April 2019 but you DON'T want (the value isn't positive and C doesn't have "some text")

Why does it work? See the truth table. Given your conditions, the only scenario in April 2019 you don't want to sum is the orange one.

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to have it not be equal to empty, I'm trying to only include the text which contains "some text" - so in my example in the question, only the first row would be included from the C column criteria. I'm trying to get all the rows, where column C includes `some text`

Comment: Could you please clarify more the "some text"? 
Do you want (1) the exact match "some text" or (2) a partial match, "some text" should be within the text on the cell?

Comment: a partial match - my requirement is as follows: `Sum all values in column D, where the date in column M is April 2019 AND (the value in column D is greater than 0 OR the value in column C contains a partial match with "some text")`

Comment: Got it. I hope it's correct now. If not, please let me know.